# iPod Touch 4G case recommendations

Tags: ipod-touch, accessories, 3rd-party

What is the best iPod Touch G4 case that clips on a belt and covers the screen?

The main annoyance I have with my current case is that I can't always reach the edges of the screen.

Comment: What is your current case? People might be better able to help you if they know what case you use now. I don't have any recommendations, but my hunch is that there aren't likely very many belt-clip cases specifically for that device.

Comment: @Ben It's the belt clip case from this link (http://www.digitalsondemand.com/p-22-15-item-accessory-bundle-for-apple-ipod-touch-4th-gen.aspx) Digitals on Demand.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [this case](http://store.griffintechnology.com/ipod/ipod-touch/survivor-ipod-touch) since the day I got mine back in June of 2011.

[image]

Its very robust, it completely covers the screen, and I have never had problems tapping the edge.

One thing you do need to be aware of though is the clip. In the picture its shown as being on the back, however I've found that to be somewhat unreliable. If you switch it around to the front (so the clip is covering the screen), its much better.

One of the (in my opinion nice) side benefits of using this case is it adds enough mass to it that you don't have to worry about the iPod just slipping out of your hand - for the week I used mine without a case, I found that it was almost too light and thin, and I kept fearing that the iPod would just fly out of my hand. Its a full body case (as you can see), so while you can't drop it into water (or a blender) and have it be fine, you can drop it a few times and it'll still be OK (handy for those first few times the belt clip fails until you learn the best way to use it! ;)